# Extract Point Cloud from a pcl::people::PersonCluster<PointT>

Tags: c++, detection, point-cloud-library

I am doing a project for the university and I need to extract the point cloud of the people to work with it. I made an ROS node adapting the code of the tutorial [Ground based rgdb people detection](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/ground_based_rgbd_people_detection.php), and now I want to publish in a topic the point cloud of the first detected cluster.

But I am not able to extract that point cloud, the definition of the class is defined here [person_cluster.h](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/person__cluster_8h_source.html). And there is a public member:

```
typedef pcl::PointCloud<PointT> PointCloud;
```

So to convert it in a `sensor_msgs::PointCloud2` I do:

```
pcl_conversions::fromPCL(clusters.at(0).PointCloud,person_msg);
```

where `person_msg` is the `PointCLoud2` message, `clusters` is a vector of `pcl::people::PersonCluster<PointT>`, and I want to publish only the first point cloud because I assume that there is only one person in the scene.

The compiler gives me this error:

> error: **invalid use of** ‘pcl::people::PersonCluster::PointCloud’
>        pcl_conversions::fromPCL(clusters.at(0).PointCloud,person_msg);

I don't have a lot of knowledge about C++ and I am not able to overcome this error. Googling that error it seems that it appears when you don't "define" well a class, but I doubt that in the pcl library they defined bad a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that are interested I resolved my problem.

In the forum of pcl I found a [post](http://www.pcl-users.org/people-detection-PointIndices-return-object-copyPointCloud-td4026364.html) where the same developer of the people detector I used gave the answer. 
So basically:

```
// Get cloud after voxeling and ground plane removal:
      PointCloudT::Ptr no_ground_cloud (new PointCloudT);
      no_ground_cloud = people_detector.getNoGroundCloud();

      // Show pointclouds of every person cluster:
      PointCloudT::Ptr cluster_cloud (new PointCloudT);
      for(std::vector<pcl::people::PersonCluster<PointT> >::iterator it = clusters.begin(); it != clusters.end(); ++it)
      {
        if (it->getPersonConfidence() > min_confidence)
        {
          // Create the pointcloud with points belonging to the current cluster:
          cluster_cloud->clear();
          pcl::PointIndices clusterIndices = it->getIndices();    // cluster indices
          std::vector<int> indices = clusterIndices.indices;
          for(unsigned int i = 0; i < indices.size(); i++)        // fill cluster cloud
          {
            PointT* p = &no_ground_cloud->points[indices[i]];
            cluster_cloud->push_back(*p);
          }

          // Visualization:
          viewer.removeAllPointClouds();
          viewer.removeAllShapes();
          pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerRGBField<PointT> rgb(cluster_cloud);
          viewer.addPointCloud<PointT> (cluster_cloud, rgb, "cluster_cloud");
          viewer.setPointCloudRenderingProperties (pcl::visualization::PCL_VISUALIZER_POINT_SIZE, 2, "cluster_cloud");
          viewer.spinOnce(500);
        }
      }
```

Actually I was not able to convert such type of point cloud in a sensor message PointCloud2, even trying to convert that pointcloud in a `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>`.

A working solution was that to use as `cluster_cloud` a type of `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>` and then using a publisher of type 
`pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>` 
Such:

```
ros::Publisher person_pub = nh.advertise<PointCloud>("personPointCloud", 1000);
```

Anyway it was no publish anything, the rviz didnt showed anything. But the viever was displaying the point cloud of the detected person. Since that pointcloud was not such I expected (if you move the arm the algorithm does no give you all the arm) it is not useful for my project so I drop it.

So still remains the problem to publish it in ros, but the problem to get the pointcloud is resolved.